# ORO storefront RestAPI related entity normalization issue

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I created model `AcmeBundle\Api\Model\AcmeLineItem` with attributes `product` and `productUnit`. Then I added a new processor which sets in the result collection of the model items and register it with tag:

```
- { name: oro.api.processor, action: get_list, group: load_data, requestType: frontend, class: AcmeBundle\Api\Model\AcmeLineItem, priority: 55 }
```

Model configuration in the `api_frontend.yml`:

```yaml
AcmeBundle\Api\Model\AcmeLineItem:
    fields:
        quantity:
            data_type: string
        productSku:
            data_type: string
        product:
            target_class: Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
            target_type: to-one
            property_path: product
        productUnit:
            target_class: Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductUnit
            target_type: to-one
    actions:
        get: false
        get_list:
            description: Get bought line items
            disable_sorting: true
        update: false
        delete: false
        delete_list: false
        create: false
```

The simple requests work fine, but with the `include` parameter an issue occurred. With value `productUnit` related items visible in response, but for `product` in value - an exception in response, with 500 code and `[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT r FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.` message.

With debugging, I found that exception occurred during the normalization of the `varianProducts` attribute of `product` entity via `@oro_api.object_normalizer`. I didn`t found a similar exception for the included products on` shippinglistitems` API methods, seams like it use a different normalizer from the product entity.

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong without debugging. The query for product variants is built by this class \Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Api\Processor\SetVariantProductsAssociationQuery. You can start from it to understand why the built query is invalid.